# Best way to generate maven modules

Tags: java, maven, dynamically-generated

I have a complex structure of maven module with involves some like 20 modules for a standard application. The standard application is also supposed to contain spring xml files and packages folder setup from the start. Right now we are copying a example application and change the name all over it. But this seems like a lot of unnecessary work. I'm wondering what software would be best to use generate this.

I saw that maven had something for this called archetype but i'm not find much documentation and example on how to use it. Maybe there is better tool for this task.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html  https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Archetypes aren't that complicated. You generate it, and you have the skeleton of a project

Comment: Archetypes are one way; but Maven is flexible, you could have a standard parent pom with the dependencies you can re-use for all your projects, or create a [bill of materials](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) which you can include as a dependency.